# Eliminar el dato más grande y más pequeño de un array

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente array llamado aux:

```
float[] aux = new float[4];
```

Como verán, el tamaño es de 4 elementos. Le añado datos de otro array más largo llamado ValRealPromov (No sé si sea necesario detallarlo, pero salto 4 espacios del array largo cada que asigno al array aux):

```
        aux[0] = ValRealProMov[x];
        aux[1] = ValRealProMov[x + 4];
        aux[2] = ValRealProMov[x + 8];
        aux[3] = ValRealProMov[x + 12];
```

Luego con el siguiente código obtengo el número más grande y el número más pequeño del array aux:

```
        float NumMay = aux[0];
        float NumMen = aux[0];
        int posMay = 0;
        int posMen = 0;
        for (int z=1;z<aux.length;z++){
            if (aux[z]>NumMay){ 
                posMay = z;
            }
            if (aux[z]<NumMen){
                posMen = z;
            } 
        }
```

Ahora, quiero eliminar los datos mayor y menor de los que obtuve la posición, el método aux.remove(posMen) no funciona, y es que necesito sumar y dividir el array completo sin esos números, ósea dejar 2 y eliminar 2 (el más grande y chico) Agradezco de antemano

Comment: Podrias utilizar otro array

Comment: `aux.remove` no funciona porque no existe. Un array es una estructura estática, te estás confundiendo con subclases de `Collection`

Comment: no es mas facil ordenar tus elementos de menor a mayor y luego cortarlo desde que empiece desde el elemento [1 ,longitud -1]

Answer (score 1):

Podrías importar la librería ArrayUtils (org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils) y usar este código.

```
float NumMay = aux[0];
float NumMen = aux[0];
int posMay = 0;
int posMen = 0;
for (int z=1;z<aux.length;z++){
    if (aux[z]>NumMay){ 
        posMay = z;
    }
    if (aux[z]<NumMen){
        posMen = z;
    } 
}

aux = ArrayUtils.remove(aux, posMay);
aux = ArrayUtils.remove(aux, posMen);
```

De esta forma estarías reescribiendo "aux" con un nuevo array en el que eliminas el valor de la posición mayor y luego lo mismo con la menor.

No es la mejor manera de hacerlo, espero que te sirva.

Answer (score -1):

para eliminar elementos de un arreglo en javascript debes usar la función splice, te explico por ejemplo en tu caso sería aux.splice(pos,n),
te explico esta función elimina n elementos a partir de la posición pos, es decir si pos=0 y n=2 elimina los dos primeros elementos, debo aclarate q además este método te devuelve las sección eliminada por si quieres usarla, ahora q pasa si aplicas la función la primera vez para eliminar el número mayor modificas el arreglo y ya la posición del menor no es la que tienes guardada si no una posición menos si el índice del mayor número era menor q el del menor número porque el arreglo ya tiene un elemento menos, espero q te sirva la respuesta

Comment: Estaría bien si no fuera que el usuario no usa javascript.

Answer (score -1):

ahora otra vía sería ordenar ese arreglo y simplemente eliminar la primera y la última posición y que estando ordenada el menor número estará al princio y el mayor número estará al final de arreglo, sería algo como esto aux.sort() para ordenar el arreglo y después sería aux.splice(0,1) y aux.splice(aux.length - 1,1) aquí tienes otra variante espero que te sirva

Comment: bueno me equivoqué y leí mal pero la lógica funciona igual ordenas el arreglo y eliminas el último y el primero si es java Arrays.sort(aux) y además no tiene ni que eliminarlos si es que quiere solo la suma solo tiene q tener en cuenta los números desde la posición 1 hasta la posición penúltima disculpa mi equivocación